# How to assign child class instance to generic (extends parent) object?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a parent class defined like this:

```
public abstract MyParent {

    public static <MP extends MyParent> MP getInstance(Object... params) {
        return new MyChild(params);
    }
}
```

where `MyChild` extends `MyParent`. The problem is the compiler wont let me return the new child because "`MyChild` cannot be converted to `MP`". If I cast before return (`return (MP) new MyChild(params);`) I get an unchecked cast warning.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Just declare the return type simply as `MyParent`.

Comment: @ernest_k Yes, my mistake

Comment: @Sweeper In that case, why keep the method generic?

Comment: The compiler is right, but more importantly, what is the point of making this method generic?  If it's always going to return a `MyChild`, then it *isn't* generic in the common sense of the term.

Comment: @ernest_k That is exactly my point. There is no need for this method to be generic.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I want to avoid to cast when I call the getInstance() method

Comment: Are you always returning a `MyChild`? In that case couldn't you just make the return type `MyChild`?

Comment: @JornVernee I have tree MyChilds, and I get a diferent Child according to the parameters

Comment: But the problem, @DSantiagoBC, is that the there is an unbounded number of possible subclasses of `MyParent` that could could serve as the type parameter, but of them all, only two -- `MyParent` and `MyChild` -- are consistent with the actual type of the returned value.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, then if I have three different child classes of MyParent, the best option is to return MyParent? I'm sorry for my lack of clarity.

Comment: yes but like others stated you can do: "public static MyParent getInstance("

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you

> have [three] MyChilds, and [] get a diferent Child according to the parameters

you have a fundamental challenge: how does the invoker of your method know which return type to expect, and how can the compiler know in advance that the type of the object actually being returned is compatible with the type the invoker expects?  Compile-time type safety absolutely depends on the latter analysis, and without that, anything you imagine doing to avoid casts is just obfuscatory.

The specific relationship between your method parameters and result type is unclear, but if it depends on anything beyond the types of the parameters, then you're done.  In that case there is no avoiding a cast or cast-equivalent somewhere.  Your better options then include

- have the method return `MyParent`, and accept that the invoker will need to cast the result if it depends on the specific subtype (but not otherwise).
- create a different and differently-named method for each actual return type.  This will avoid the need for the invoker to cast, but it may require provision for an exception in the event that the given parameters do not correspond to an object of the correct type for the method called.

Of course, you may also be able to modify the method so that the return type **is** based on the types of the parameters.  For example, you might

- include a [type-token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12570045/2402272) among the method paramerers.  For this to serve as other than a cast equivalent, however, the method needs somehow to associate the type token with the other parameters, or to use it to genuinely select the return type, or coerce the return value to the specified type.

Comment: I'm going to use your second option because of understandability and control. Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

MP can be anything that extends MyParent, but MyChild is not going to be a subclass of every subclass of MyParent.

I think your intention here is to have getInstance return an instance of MyParent instead of having it return a generic MP.